# Find cofactors of adj(A) in terms of |A|

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} &a_{23} & a_{24} \\a_{31} & a_{32} &  a_{33} & a_{34}\\a_{41}&a_{42}&a_{43}&a_{44} \end{pmatrix}$

Let $A'$ be a matrix formed by using corresponding cofactors of $a_{ii}$'s

Let $A'= \begin{pmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & A_{14}\\ A_{21} & A_{22} &A_{23} & A_{24} \\A_{31} & A_{32} &  A_{33} & A_{34}\\A_{41}&A_{42}&A_{43}&A_{44} \end{pmatrix}$

where $A_{ii}$ is cofactor of $a_{ii}$.

Prove that cofactor of $A_{11}=a_{11}\left(det(A)\right)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjugate matrix is the transpose of $A'$. It satisfies the property that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}
\adj(A)A=\det(A)I
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix of the appropriate size, say $n$. Assuming $\det(A)\ne0$, we conclude that
$$
\det(\adj(A))\det(A)=(\det(A))^n
$$
Therefore we have
$$
\adj(\adj(A))\adj(A)=(\det(A))^{n-1}I
$$
whence your relation.

For the case $\det(A)=0$, it takes a bit of care, but it's valid as well.

Comment: True. But how do I get cofactor of $A_{11}$

Comment: @PankajSinha Multiply both sides of the last relation by $A$. You'll discover that the cofactor of $A_{11}$ is $a_{11}(\det(A))^{n-2}$; in your case $n=4$, so the statement you have to prove is incorrect.

Comment: Yes. You are correct.